# insert only combination of fields not existing in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to insert ONLY records that do not exist (as a combo) in another table. Here it is:

This is the Source table:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybcPh.png)

This is the Target table:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKHi5.png)

So In this case, I would need to add into the target table only:

```
107 Allentown
107 Annville
107 Baltimore
```

What would be the best way to do it as a combo? Any suggestions appreciated.

I am currently doing it with a cursor:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Locations (ClientID, name)
SELECT DISTINCT CL.ClientID, TC.[name]
FROM TMPCTable TC 
JOIN CLIENTS        CL ON TC.[Client Code] = CL.[ClientCode]
LEFT JOIN locations L1 ON L1.Location      = TC.[Name] AND L1.ClientID = CL.CLIENTID
WHERE l1.id IS NULL
```

but for some reason, it is leaving some behind. I have a unique constraint for both fields as a combo (ClientID, Name)

Comment: Please don't use images, use formatted text

Comment: Table structures???

Comment: `I am currently doing it with a cursor` Please include the cursor query in the question

Comment: Where [`not exists`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#e-using-not-exists)?

Answer (score 0):

How about using the `except` **set** operator?

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Locations (ClientID, name)
select [ClientID], [name] from TMPTable
except
select [ClientID], [name] from Locations
```